# Android layout with one side round

Tags: android, xml, image, layout, view

Who can help me make some round as in the picture?

[image]

Original picture :

[image]

Comment: I think you can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. But if you're trying to create a round image (like the profile pic in your Images), you have multiple options.

The simplest option is to use a library. There are multiple libraries out there, but my favourite would be:
https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

If you don't wish to use a library, you could use a XML shape to give a rounded shape to your ImageView. You can look at this answer for that:
[How to make an ImageView with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2459916/3286614)